# Configuring Azure AD B2C ApiScopes and ApiUrl

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm having trouble configuring an AspNet Core 2.1 website to use Azure AD B2C for authentication. I've got [this example](https://github.com/chrispadgettlivecom/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNetCore21) to work, but when I try to adapt it to my own AD B2C tenant I get an invalid operation exception in the following code:

```
   private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext context)
    {
        var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(context.Options.ClientSecret);
        var userId = context.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        var tokenCache = new SessionTokenCache(context.HttpContext, userId);

        var confidentialClientApplication = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
            context.Options.ClientId,
            context.Options.Authority,
            _options.RedirectUri,
            clientCredential,
            tokenCache.GetInstance(),
            null);

        try
        {
            // this next line throws the exception
            var authenticationResult = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(context.ProtocolMessage.Code, _options.ApiScopes.Split(' '));
            context.HandleCodeRedemption(authenticationResult.AccessToken, authenticationResult.IdToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // TODO: Handle
            throw;
        }
    }
```

The exception detail is:

> Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException   HResult=0x80131500
>   Message=AADSTS50049: Unknown or invalid instance. Trace ID:
>   1391c6be-c8f7-4c05-a575-b4998f79d800 Correlation ID:
>   8b83a695-000f-44c2-99c1-d779725342da Timestamp: 2018-09-27 02:05:02Z
>   Source=Microsoft.Identity.Client   StackTrace:    at
>   Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.OAuth2.OAuth2Client.CreateErrorResponse(HttpResponse
>   response, RequestContext requestContext)    at
>   Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.OAuth2.OAuth2Client.CreateResponse[T](HttpResponse
>   response, RequestContext requestContext, Boolean addCorrelationId)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.OAuth2.OAuth2Client.d__9`1.MoveNext()
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.OAuth2.OAuth2Client.<DiscoverAadInstanceAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Instance.AadAuthority.<GetOpenIdConfigurationEndpointAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Instance.Authority.<ResolveEndpointsAsync>d__45.MoveNext()
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.<ResolveAuthorityEndpointsAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.<PreTokenRequestAsync>d__36.MoveNext()
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.<RunAsync>d__33.MoveNext()
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Identity.Client.ConfidentialClientApplication.<AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeCommonAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Identity.Client.ConfidentialClientApplication.<AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   RideMonitorSite.AzureADB2COpenIdConnectOptionsConfigurator.d__5.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Programming\RideMonitorServer\RideMonitorSite\AzureADB2COpenIDConnectOptionsConfigurator.cs:line
>   58

From examining the arguments passed to the function that throws the exception, I noticed that _options.ApiScopes is set to:

> https://ridemonitor.onmicrosoft.com/api/user.read

which is as I configured it in the app. The tenant app configuration has the api url set to the "folder" of that Url (i.e., everything excluding the user.read)...but I'm not sure what other configuration I should be doing in the tenant app. How does it know what user.read means?

If someone can point me to some introductory material on how AD B2C should be set up, that would be appreciated. The stuff I've found so far presumes a level of knowledge that I clearly don't have.

Comment: What is `context.Options.Authority` set to?

Comment: context.Options.Authority is set to https://ridemonitor.b2clogin.com/ridemonitor.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_SignUpIn/v2.0

The full version of that text is

https://ridemonitor.b2clogin.com/ridemonitor.onmicrosoft.com

+ /b2c_1_SignUpIn/v2.0

Sorry, I don't know how to not have the editor truncate long urls, so I had to break it up; the " + " is not actually part of the url

Comment: If you are using the `b2clogin.com` domain, then you must set the `ConfidentialClientApplication.ValidateAuthority` property to `false` because this domain is not recognized by MSAL.

Comment: Progress! A different exception was thrown: There was an error deserializing the object of type Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.OAuth2.TokenResponse. Encountered unexpected character '<'. Thoughts?

Comment: Never mind; I figured out the problem -- a badly formatted Instance property. For some reason, I left off the /tfp component of the url. If you'd care to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the **your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com** domain with MSAL, then (at the time of this writing) you must:

1. Ensure **Authority** contains [the `/tfp` path](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/blob/ff5b29d31802fa11b23c62cfbf721128552e4243/src/Microsoft.Identity.Client/Internal/Instance/B2CAuthority.cs#L36) because this is [how MSAL infers it is interacting with an Azure AD B2C tenant](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/blob/ff5b29d31802fa11b23c62cfbf721128552e4243/src/Microsoft.Identity.Client/Internal/Instance/Authority.cs#L131).
2. [Set the **ValidateAuthority** to `false`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin#set-the-validateauthority-property).